# Why does LLVM pass nonsense values to an FFI function?

Tags: c++, linker, clang, llvm, ffi

I have a C++ header declared like:

```
struct Inner {
    // ...
};

struct MyStruct {
    Inner*  _inner;
    size_t  _x;
    size_t  _y;
};

extern "C" {
    MyStruct my_fn(MyStruct* s, bool flag_1, bool flag_2);
};
```

...which I'm compiling with `clang` into a shared library, whose functions I'm trying to invoke from LLVM code:

```
%"Inner" = type {i64, i64}
%"MyStruct" = type {%"Inner"*, i64, i64}

declare %"MyStruct" @"my_fn"(%"MyStruct"* %".1", i1 %".2", i1 %".3") 

define void @"main"()
{
entry:
  %".stack_buf_ptr" = alloca %"MyStruct"
  ; ... assign elements of %.stack_buf_ptr ...
  %".15" = call %"MyStruct" @"my_fn"(%"MyStruct"* %".stack_buf_ptr", i1 true, i1 true)
}
```

The program crashes inside `my_fn`. However, what's peculiar is that the **passed arguments have nonsense values**, which I can see when I print them from `my_fn`, or if I inspect them in a debugger. Specifically, the **first argument has the nonsense pointer value "0x7".**

From reading the LLVM IR, I don't know how this is possible— the pointer is provided directly by LLVM's own `alloca` instruction. I get similar behavior if I try to pass the address of a global variable. More bizarrely, some of my other called functions with similar (but not identical) signatures work just fine.

The only explanation I can think of is a disagreement in calling convention, but it doesn't appear to be wrong in either case— the function is declared inside `extern "C" { ... }`, and when I use `nm` on the compiled shared library I can see that `my_fn` obeys the `cdecl` naming convention (it's listed as `_my_fn`). I also read from the documentation that LLVM function declarations default to `cdecl`.

I don't really know what to look at next. Could there be some reason why my types/signatures aren't matching in binary layout? Are there compiler settings for the shared library I should check that could fix/break things? What could be going on?

Why would the above LLVM code pass nonsense values to `my_fn()`?

Comment: Did you hand write that llvm code?  Have you compared it to what clang produces given naive C++ code that acts similarly?  Can you strip out the initialization and provide a [mcve] that fully reproduces the problem?

Comment: Returning a value that does not fit a register can be confusing ABI-wise.. I would try to refactor so that `my_fn` takes an output parameter and return void, and see if that works.

Comment: @sbabbi @Yakk Both of those comments were helpful and I believe have led me to the problem— LLVM doesn't automatically handle the return of struct values (!!); the caller has to know to alloca space and pass a magic hidden argument: https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-March/097690.html . Compiling a call to the same function using C and `clang -S -emit-llvm` confirmed that this is happening. I'll post a separate question about how to detect when this is necessary.